# How to switch table content when needed?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I want to store 6 types of black, white and grey lists into my database. These lists contain a few words. Whenever someone notices a new word that should be added to one of the lists, they can simply add that new word to the database.

The problem I am facing is the the structure of the tables. I don't know if I have the right solution. I want to get the data as fast as I can. So I thought having a table "List" and table "Content" would do the trick. The image below shows you want I mean.[image]

When the listId is for instance "Blacklist" then it would show the content that is paired with it. The problem with this solution is that I don't know how that switch works. How does a table switch contents when needed, how do I program that in my database?

Or should I just make a superclass with subclasses? Like the image below.[image]

Maybe I am totally missing the point and neither of these designs will help me with storing these 6 lists the right way. My goal is to get the data as fast as I can with my application. The content of these lists should be accessible at any time.

Any advice or tutorials are very welcome!

Comment: why not just 2 tables, one for the lists and a second table with the words and a reference to the ID of the relevant list?

Comment: @Paolo How do I make that? Do you have any tutorials I could use?

Comment: Hi @user3599415.  Are you asking how to make the tables, how to query them, or both?

Comment: @destination-data Both:)

Comment: You could start with the MySQL tutorial (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tutorial.html).

Comment: @destination-data Thanks! But how do I query them?

Comment: Can you remove the MySQL or SQL-Server tag.  These are separate products, and the solutions from one won't always work on the other.  Knowing which you are using will help us help you.  Can you also tell us what you application will be written in?  Do you have any sample code you can share?b  You first idea seems to be along the right lines (2 tables, list and content).  To query these you will need learn abouts JOINs and the WHERE clause.

Comment: The WROX book on database design is excellent.